# FileNotFoundException: Creates child folder instead of file

Tags: java, android, file

I just started to work with files today with Android and have been pulling my hair out all day. This throws a FileNotFoundException:

```
public void writeConfig(){
            try {
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "AppName", "TimetableConfiguration");
                if (!file.mkdirs()) {
                    P.rint("Couldn't create directory");
                }
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fileOutputStream.write(getActivity().getSharedPreferences("periods", MODE_PRIVATE).getString("periods", null).getBytes());
            fileOutputStream.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                P.rint("Didn't find file");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Any ideas?
I notice that instead of creating a file, it creates a child folder. Why is it doing this?
Thanks for any help :)

Comment: *File not found* seems to be pretty clear, doesn't it? The file wasn't found. Did you look to make sure the file was there? We can't do that for you. If it's not there, you'll get a FileNotFoundException. Your current code just assumes that `new FileOutputStream(file)` succeeds. Regarding your *other question*, can't you read the documentation to find out how that function works?

Comment: @KenWhite I want to know why the file wasn't created in the first place.

Comment: Well, the most common reasons are either trying to create it in an invalid location or not having the required permissions. Again, neither of those are things we can check for you. Using a debugger can help you figure it out, though.

Comment: Another piece of advice: When FileNotFoundException is thrown, you have information available in `e` - stop throwing it away and providing your own useless message, and see what information is available in that exception object that might be of use to you. It's pretty silly to have that information available to you and not use it. The documentation can tell you what details `FileNotFoundException` can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> FileNotFoundException: Creates child folder instead of file

Yes. That is what you do.

You first create with mkdirs() a directory with a certain name.

After that you try to create a file with the same name which is impossible as there cannot be two files or directories with the same name.

So have a look and you will find that directory.

Well you had deduced most all yourself already. Now try to understand your code.

> if (!file.mkdirs()) {
>                       P.rint("Couldn't create directory");

You will see that printed every time you repeat the code. You should have seen this too. And have told us.

You should only call mkdirs if the directory does not exist yet.